# fbDidLogin or fbDidNotLogin not called

Tags: facebook, sos, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to integrate facebook login in my existing app. I have the openURL and handleOpenURL methods in AppDelegate.m, but i initialize facebook object in one of the view Controller on click of a button. so my fbDidLogin method is in the viewController, which never gets called. Neither is the fbDidNotLogin is called.

Is it something wrong I am doing?

Comment: Hello are you trying to open the login dialog inside your app itself?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because i hadn´t set the URL types in the info.plist like it says on the tutorial http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#register

Answer (score 0):

And I have forgotten to implement the only method in the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [[FacebookService sharedInstance].facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

FacebookService - is my wrapper singletone class, that contains instance og facebook
the error was the same